# Python data structure like dict

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, data-structures, standards

Online I found some code that used the variable `explored`. 
This variable is implemented like a dictionary: `explored = {rootId}`, but it doesn't have key-value association, moreover this variabile uses the function `.add(elem)` while the dict doesn't have this function.
eg. `explored.add(elem)`.

Which data structure is that? (I'm using python 3.6.3)

Comment: Could you share the code that you found online?

Comment: print(type(THE_UNKNOWN THINGY))

Comment: [You mean a `set`?](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: Looks like a `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). There are also online [examples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set#change) that use the methods you mentioned.

Next time you wonder, I suggest you just print the type, like this:

```
print(type(explored));
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a set, it has a method "add", but you could simply print the type, such as:

```
print(type(explored))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `set` datastructure.
Here's a link to it on the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets